# How to take derivative $\phi(x) = \langle T(x)\cdot f(x), g(x)\rangle$ for transformations $f, g, T$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be open. Given $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^n,
>  g:U\to\mathbb{R}^p$ and $T:U\to L(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^p)$ define
>   $\phi:U\to\mathbb{R}$ by doing $\phi(x) = \langle T(x)\cdot f(x),
>  g(x)\rangle$. For $x\in U$ and $h\in \mathbb{R}^m$ arbitrary, find
>   $\phi'(x)\cdot h$

Which rule should I use to take this derivative? Chain rule? There are lots of compositions, I'm lost. For example, I should first do the derivative of the outer function, which is $\langle x,y\rangle$ and multiply by the derivative of the inside, right? But what is the derivative of that thing?